# oops something went wrong - the page didn't load maps correctly

Tags: google-maps

Then goes on to say look in console. Problem is it works fine on desktop, no problems at all. It was also working fine on mobile 2 days ago and no changes. So on mobile there is no console. I have even tried Googles example @ https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple with obviously my API key and the same problem, works fine on desktop in all browser but not on mobile in either chrome and firefox. Thing is I am also getting the same problem with recapture (just spins forever), works fine on desktop but not on mobile chrome but works on mobile phone with firefox. This is driving me crazy. I have tried tow different phones.

Answer (score 0):

OK ended up creating a new API key and it works, may have been something to do with a long list of credential addresses that I had on that api, no idea.